# How do I move bones from one armature to another armature in the outliner?

Tags: outliner

[image]

I would like to make sure all these bones are in a single armature so I can select them all in edit mode.

Thanks

Comment: @gandalf3, I think marking this as a duplicate of the other question is a mistake because of significant differences between this question, and the one nominated as a duplicate. That question asked merely about joining multiple armatures into one. This question specifically asks about doing so using the outliner editor window. I'm voting to reopen the question.

Comment: In the case of using the outliner, the first object can be selected in the outliner editor window by left clicking on the object. The second (and subsequent) objects can be selected by right-clicking on the object, and choosing "select" from the context menu, and pressing the space bar, searching for "join", and selecting that from the context menu..

Comment: @brasshat Hm.. Wasn't sure if the OP specifically wanted to do this from the outliner and only from the outliner, as they only referenced it in the title. If the OP *does* want an outliner-specific answer, then this question can be always re-opened